# Handling Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to route to a page when user clicks on the link.
I have Created a dynamic Link and link redirects to the app.
I want to run onLink function of Firebase Dynamic Link but the function is giving error

The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
Undefined class 'OnLinkErrorException'.

[image: Here is my code with error]

Comment: Do you want to redirect from app to a link through a link? Please clarify your concern.

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I want to redirect user to a new Screen when clicked on link But I am getting this errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way maybe it will help you.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
Navigator.pushNamed(context, dynamicLinkData.link.path);
}).onError((error) {
    // Handle errors
});
```

or just just follow this [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive)